# My shell script to symlink a file from one directory to another is broken

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a file within a Dropbox directory and I want to symlink it to my home/user directory.

I'm trying to automate it with a shell script like so...

```
db="$HOME/Dropbox/Fresh\ Install"
ln -s $db/README.md $HOME/symlinked.txt
```

...but all that happens is when I run `sh provision.sh` I get the error `ln: /Users/<user>/symlinked.txt: No such file or directory`

I'm guessing the problem is related to the path pointing to a folder whose name has a space inside it.

I've tried different variations to get it to work but can't figure it out.

Tried to use "command substitution" as well but couldn't understand how it was relevant to the problem.

Any help to get this working appreciated.

Note: I'm using zsh but as far as I'm aware running this simple bash script shouldn't be an issue/conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslashes aren't processed when expanding variables. You need to quote the variable.

```
db="$HOME/Dropbox/Fresh Install"
ln -s "$db"/README.md $HOME/symlinked.txt
```

In general, it's best to always [quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) variables unless you know you want the value to be subjected to word splitting and wildcard expansion.